# Magento 2.2.5 - JS errors in console only on Hard Fresh(Ctrl+F5)

Tags: magento2, error, console

[image]

The above issues occur only on hard refresh(Ctrl+F5) and not on normal refresh(F5).

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: You've to add dependencies to requirejs-config.js like below answer, try to implement external js in such a way @EjilarasanJ

Answer (score 1):

I have implement **flexslider** feature by the below way,

Try this,

First Step : Add the source files which is required for **flexslider** implementation.

1. Add **jquery.flexslider.js** to the below path

> app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/web/js/jquery.flexslider.js

2. Add **jquery.flexslider.css** to the below path

> app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/web/css/flexslider.css

then add css into your store

> app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

then add the below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/flexslider.css" />
</head>
</page>
```

Second Step : Implementation of **flexslider** feature in to your store

1. Add **requirejs-config.js** to the below path.

> app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/requirejs-config.js

and add the below code in it

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'flexslider': 'js/jquery.flexslider'
},
shim: {
    'flexslider': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
}
};
```

2. Final step is to trigger the js wherever you want in my case, I would need it in all the pages so I triggered it in header.phtml inside the theme.

Script to trigger the external js

```
require(['jquery','flexslider'],function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
     /*flexslider code*/
});
});
```

Hope it helps anyone, who's trying to add external js to their store. It would be any external script it may **owl carousel** or **box slider** js extension etc..,

Peace :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check the above points and reach you.

Comment: Not working as expected. Still, the issue exists.

Comment: Upgraded jquery-ui from 1.10 to 1.12 except the flexslider issue other issues have been resolved.